# How to convert a bar chart into a triangle shaped chart using Chart JS?

Tags: javascript, chart.js, data-visualization, bar-chart, triangle

How to convert a bar chart into a triangle shaped chart  using Chart JS ?

For eg: Sample Bar Chart : How to convert it into triangles instead of bars ?

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
        datasets: [{
            label: '# of Votes',
            data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            y: {
                beginAtZero: true
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi, SO aren't a coding workforce. We're here for help, but, can you try it and post some of your tests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to implement your own custom chart type to do this since it's not possible by default, you can read here in the documentation how to implement your own chart type: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/developers/charts.html

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [`scatter`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/scatter.html) chart and define individual `datasets` for each value.

Please take a look at your amended code and see how it works.

```js
const labels = ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'];
const data = [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3];
const colors = ['255, 99, 132', '54, 162, 235', '255, 206, 86', '75, 192, 192', '153, 102, 255', '255, 159, 64'];

const datasets = labels.map((l, i) => ({
  label: l,
  data: [{ x: i + 1 - 0.45, y: 0 }, { x: i + 1, y: data[i] }, { x: i + 1 + 0.45, y: 0 }],
  fill: true,
  backgroundColor: 'rgba(' + colors[i] + ', 0.2)',
  borderColor: 'rgb(' + colors[i] + ')',
  showLine: true,
  borderWidth: 1,
  lineTension: 0,
  pointRadius: 0,
  pointHitRadius: 0
}));

new Chart('myChart', {
  type: 'scatter',
  data: {
    datasets: datasets
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      y: {
        beginAtZero: true
      },
      x: {
        min: 0,
        max: labels.length + 1,
        ticks: {
          callback: (v, i) => labels[i - 1] 
        },
        grid: {
          display: false
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.3.2/chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" height="110"></canvas>
```